# How to automate file clean up in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently working on a backend api.

I need to read a particular file on my working directory, process it and write back to it whenever I run `npm run build`

The reason I am doing this is because the system that is generating the file leaves it malformed sometimes, so I need to clean it up and save again without doing it manually.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "pre" build step (script) in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "your-build-command",
    "prebuild": "node clean-up-file.js"
  }
}
```

Now when you run `npm run build` the script in `prebuild` will execute beforehand.

Keep in mind that if you execute your build command without npm, the "prebuild" script won't be triggered.

Comment: You are my hero!!! Worked like a charm...Thanks a billion